# How to create a circular Outlined button with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-button, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

I am trying to create a circular `OutlinedButton` with an icon in the center without text.

```
    OutlinedButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        shape = CircleShape,
        border= BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Blue)
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "content description")
    }
```

The final button has an oval shape:

[image]

Using an `IconButton`:

```
    IconButton(onClick = {  },
        modifier = Modifier
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Red)
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "content description",tint = Color.Red)
    }
```

This is the final result:

[image]

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use the **`OutlinedButton`** removing the `contentPadding`.
Something like:

```
    OutlinedButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        modifier= Modifier.size(50.dp),  //avoid the oval shape
        shape = CircleShape,
        border= BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Blue),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),  //avoid the little icon
        colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(contentColor =  Color.Blue)
    ) {
         Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "content description")
    }
```

[image]

or the **`IconButton`** removing the `clip` modifier and using the `shape` inside the `border` parameter:

```
    IconButton(onClick = {  },
          modifier = Modifier
              .then(Modifier.size(50.dp))
              .border(1.dp, Color.Red, shape = CircleShape)
              ) {
        Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "content description", tint = Color.Red)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: how can I set the icon size inside the outlined button? it seems it is not possible...

Answer (score 1):

There is not an outlined icon button component in the M2 package (`androidx.compose.material`), but in M3 (`androidx.compose.material3`), since [v1.0.0-alpha10](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.0.0-alpha10) released April 20, 2022, there is an [`OutlinedIconButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#OutlinedIconButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.IconButtonColors,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function0)), you can use it as follows:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedIconButton

OutlinedIconButton(onClick = { /* doSomething() */ }) {
    Icon(Icons.Outlined.Lock, contentDescription = "Localized description")
}
```

Similarly there are `FilledIconButton` and `FilledTonalIconButton` for the other M3 styles.