# Android: Jetpack compose: How to create a button with an Icon in it?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This question is more about why Jetpack compose is so unintuitive. I am trying to better understand this library.

With the below composable

```
fun RoundedButton(modifier: Modifier, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp)) {
        Button(
            onClick = { /* ... */ },
            shape = CircleShape,
        ) {
            // Inner content including an icon and a text label
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = "Favorite",
                modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
            )
        }

    }
}
```

I get this

[image: rounded button]

So one would assume, that in order to make it rounded I can just set the size (width and height) to an value, and if I do so

```
@Composable
fun RoundedButton(modifier: Modifier, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp)) {
        Button(
            onClick = { /* ... */ },
            shape = CircleShape,
            modifier = modifier.size(40.dp)
        ) {
            // Inner content including an icon and a text label
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = "Favorite",
                modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
            )
        }

    }
}
```

I get this.

[image]

**Question:**

I do realise that there are other variations of `Button` out there like `IconButton` etc, but why make simple things so complicated that you cannot arrive at `RoundedButton` or `IconButton` from a `Button`?

Comment: `Button()` is from Compose Material. Material Design is an opinionated design system, including such things as minimum padding. If you do not like those opinions, do not use Compose Material, but instead create your own design system based on non-Material composables. Or, find other composables within Compose Material that better fit your needs -- `FloatingActionButton()` might work for your use case.

Comment: Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66671902/how-to-create-a-circular-outlined-button-with-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 4):

The `Button` Composable has a default `contentPadding`.

```
object ButtonDefaults {

    private val ButtonHorizontalPadding = 24.dp
    private val ButtonVerticalPadding = 8.dp

    ...
}
```

That's why when you set the size to `40.dp` the `Icon` is not visible. If you set the `contentPadding` to `1.dp` (I'm not sure if 0.dp works), you can see the Icon.

```
@Composable
fun RoundedButton(modifier: Modifier, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp)) {
        Button(
            onClick = { /* ... */ },
            shape = CircleShape,
            modifier = modifier.size(40.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(1.dp)
        ) {
            // Inner content including an icon and a text label
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = "Favorite",
                modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
            )
        }

    }
}
```